# Error in version installing laravel-scout-elastic

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch in my laravel 5.7.11 app and making some search I found 
plugin laravel-scout-elastic ( https://github.com/ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic ) 
and I tried firstly elasticsearch/elasticsearch and laravel-scout-elastic plugin after and the last show error:

```
$ composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Using version ^6.0 for elasticsearch/elasticsearch
./composer.json has been updated
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing react/promise (v2.7.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (v6.0.1): Downloading (100%)         
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: aloha/twilio
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
Discovered Package: davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: itsgoingd/clockwork
Discovered Package: jrean/laravel-user-verification
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: mews/captcha
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: orangehill/iseed
Discovered Package: proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation
Discovered Package: rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-activitylog
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-tags
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-translatable
Discovered Package: themsaid/laravel-mail-preview
Discovered Package: unisharp/laravel-filemanager
Discovered Package: xethron/migrations-generator
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Proengsoft\JsValidation\JsValidationServiceProvider" --tag=public --force
Copied Directory [/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/public] To [/public/vendor/jsvalidation]
Publishing complete.
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes$ composer require tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Using version ^4.0 for tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic
./composer.json has been updated
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/serge/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev, v6.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v6.0.1, 5.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev, v6.0.1].
    - tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic 4.0.0 requires elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^5.0 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[5.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic ^4.0 -> satisfiable by tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic[4.0.0].
    - Installation request for elasticsearch/elasticsearch (locked at v6.0.1, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v6.0.1].
```

Can you advice me which versions have I to install and how ? I mean if I have to set version of packeges in console command?

Please, show format of these commands...

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try my package https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch
It has the same features as tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic but with the import command

Answer (score 0):

You must first install Scout via the following command:

```
composer require laravel/scout "5.0.x-dev"
```